# jQuery clone returns two table rows at a time, need one

Tags: jquery

Why does jQuery clone return two table rows at a time? I want it to return a `tr` at a time on `click` of a link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(".tr_clone_add").on('click', function() {
        $('.tr_clone').clone(false).appendTo('table tbody');
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<th>Type</th>
<th>Selection</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Incl. Price</th>
<th>VAT Type</th>
<th>Disc % </th>
<th>Discount</th>
<th>Exclusive</th>
<th>Vat</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th></th>

<tbody>
    <!-- <input type="text" name="user" id="users" autocomplete="off"> -->
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td>
            <select class="form-control myselect" name="acc_type">
                <option selected="selected">Account</option>
                <!-- <option>John Doe</option>-->
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>

            <select class="form-control myselect account" name="acc_no" onchange="get_quote($(this).val())">
                <option selected="selected">select Item</option>
                <?php $accounts = $pdo->query("select acc_no,acc_name from coa")->fetchall();?>
                    <?php foreach($accounts as $item):?>
                        <option value="<?=$item['acc_no']; ?>">
                            <?=$item['acc_name']; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="">
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="tr_clone_add"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 16px"></i></a>  &nbsp&nbsp -->
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add">
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Del" class="del">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: because you select all the rows with the class...

Comment: I suspect you mean on the second click. And on third you'd get four. see a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all the rows with the class. If you do not want to select all the rows, you need to remove the class after you clone it.

```
$(".tr_clone_add").on('click', function() {        
    $('.tr_clone').clone(false).removeClass("tr_clone").appendTo('table tbody'); 
});
```